# Difference between h and T in harvey adjusted Diebold and Mariano test?

Tags: forecasting, diebold-mariano-test

I am looking into comparing the predictive accuracy of forecasts of different models against a benchmark model. For this I have looked into the Diebold-Mariano test statistic, however I am using the modified Harvey, Leybourne and Newbold version of this test and I do not understand the difference between the used T and h in this modification?

The original DM-statistic value is multiplied by the square root of:

```
[T + 1 - 2h + h(h-1)/T]/T
```

As far as I can see, the T and h will be equal for h-period forecast and as T being the length of the forecast errors?

Here is some provided reference: https://www.bankofcanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/wp04-2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$h$ is the forecast horizon, whereas $T$ is the sample size for the loss differentials.

For example, if I have data $Y_1, ..., Y_{100}$, I could construct a sequence of 2-step-ahead forecasts like this:

1. Fit my model on $Y_1, ..., Y_{90}$, and derive $\hat{Y}_{92}$.
2. Fit my model on $Y_1, ..., Y_{91}$, and derive $\hat{Y}_{93}$.

...

9. Fit my model on $Y_1, ..., Y_{98}$, and derive $\hat{Y}_{100}$.

I then evaluate my loss function for each of $L(Y_i, \hat{Y}_i)$, for $i=92,...,100$. I do the same for my benchmark model and obtain loss differentials $d_{92},...,d_{100}$.

In this example, we have $h=2$ and $T=9$.

Comment: Okey, so h is sort of the time increments of the total forecasted horizon?

And, just a question, if you were to do as the example, in e.g. step 3 through 9, would you use Yhat_92 or Y_92 when estimating e.g. Yhat_94?
(Sorry, for the math, I don't know how to use math mode here...)

Comment: $h$ is the number of steps ahead for the forecast, yes. When forecasting for $\hat{Y}_{94}$, you would base it on the actual data up to $Y_{92}$, otherwise it would not be a 2-step-ahead forecast (if you use only $Y_1,...,Y_{90}$, it is a 4-step-ahead forecast).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying.